# Regex different than something else

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I want to do something that looks very easy. I just want to do a regex of the oposite of this expresion:

(.*)"number"(.*)1.1.2(.*)

So I just want to get the text if for example: "number":2.2.2 but not if "number":1.1.2

I have tried with [^] but it only works with some set of numbers or letters.
I'm trying my regex in http://regexpal.com/

EDITED: I'm sorry if I did not explained correctly: I want to do something like [^1234] but applied to all the regex: so something like [^((.*)"number"(.*)1.1.2(.*))]

EDITED2: If the text is "number":1.3.4 I will select the text but if the text is "number":1.1.2 I don't select anything. 
Thanks!

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking... You want any `\d\.\d\.\d\.\d` except `\d\.1\.1\.2` right?

Comment: Do you only want "number":1.1.2, I do NOT understand the purpose of the question if so

Comment: Click "permalink" at the bottom of regexpal and give us the URL so we can see what you are trying to do. Your question is unclear.

Comment: Give an example of what you expect to match and don't expect to match

Comment: Is "number" supposed to represent a number or the actual text "number"?

Comment: Its the actual text "number".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty sure after your edits that this accomplishes what you want:

```
"number":(?!1\.1\.2)\d\.\d\.\d(.*)
```

This works by literally matching `"number":`, and then using a negative lookahead (`(?!...)`).  This is a zero-width assertion (meaning it doesn't actually match anything, it just makes sure something is true).  In this negative lookahead, we make sure the next characters are not `1\.1\.2` (notice I escape the periods, since `.` means "any character").  As long as `1.1.2` does not follow `"number":`, then we go ahead and match any set of digits `\d\.\d\.\d` followed by capturing everything else with `(.*)`.

[**Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/kR0iT9)

Comment: Thats what I wanted. Thank you Sam